# Is it possible to charge this MS Surface Pro through the USB-C port?

Tags: microsoft-surface

I have used an MS Surface Pro. (At least I think that's what it is?)

It doesn't say anywhere on it what it is. It has a Micrsoft logo on it and I have a vague recollection of msinfo32 saying that it was MS Surface Pro. (Maybe Surface Pro 3, I don't recall.)

At the moment it’s not starting up. At one point it flashed on for a moment.

I think maybe it’s possible that it’s a dead battery. Though I’ve had it plugged in for a few minutes and it hasn’t helped and at the moment it's not even flicking on for a moment.

It has a USB-C socket on it but I’m not sure if that's for charging (inputting power), or if it's for plugging in a USB-C device, or for either?!

Here is a picture

[image]

That USB cable in there is on the other end connected to an AC/DC hub with USB ports. So I’m trying to power it via that. I’m wondering if that's correct?

**Added**

Here are some more pictures of this laptop that has no label. And it might help see whether or not it has a USB-C port or something that just looks a bit like a USB-C port.

[image]

And since it was suggeseted that the "label" would be under the "kickstand". I do see  something printed there. 1901 64GB followed by some long number.

[image]

Comment: Microsoft Surface devices cannot be charged through Type-C they come with their own power connector. However, all OEM devices have a COA, and in the case of Microsoft Surface, devices also have a Microsoft logo. Microsoft Surface Pro 3s most definitely CANNOT be charged through Type-C.  Provide a screenshot of each side with the ports, I can easily, provide information on which is the charging port. Of course without the power connector that information is sort of useless as they are not exactly sold at commercial stores or Amazon at least not authenticate cables.

Comment: AT Ramhound Ok, there is a port that looks a bit like a slot, so looks like could fit either some card, or not a card, but some charger connector(a bit like the connector of  a macbook charger that goes into a macbook).  I have now ordered a charger for the surface pro, I can see it'd fit into the slot.,. Your comment has basically solved it 'cos by ruling out the USB it's clear to me how it's charged. You can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: Hopefully you didn’t purchase a MacBook connector.

Comment: yeah I purchased a surface pro charger, coming soon. Hopefully when I plugged a USB cable in the USB-C to try to charge it from an ACDC, it didn't damage it. I know not to plug a wrong charger in eg different voltages can be an issue.. And for those slot ones i'd be extra careful

Comment: The surface pro I have will USB charge with USB pd. I think it's a 7 so exact models matter

Comment: @JourneymanGeek looking here https://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-Surface-Pro-12-3-Tablet/dp/B09S7N3Y69/  the 7 has a USB-A next to the USB-C.  I have no USB-A on mine

Comment: The product label should be under the kickstand.

Comment: AT Ramhound, okay i've included a pic from under the kickstand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That is a Microsoft Surface Go 2 and it can be charged via USB C via Power Delivery (PD).

#### While there are Microsoft specific chargers for the power-only connection, you don’t need that if you have a USB C charger that uses Power Delivery (PD).

That device you have is a [Microsoft Surface Go 2 (1901)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_Go_2). I did a Google search for “[1901 surface](https://www.google.com/search?q=Microsoft%20Surface%20Go%202%20(1901))” and that is what consistently shows up.

According to the specs on Wikipedia, it seems like it uses a 24W charger. Microsoft has some [generic advice for charging Surface devices](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/usb-c-and-fast-charging-for-surface-d320ab19-e4ed-c36d-7458-7d7aec69d34a) with USB C; but that stuff is fairly generic.

In my experience, if the device needs 24W it can work well with even an 18W or 20W USB C charger but will charge more slowly. But it doesn’t mean much if you want to plug it in overnight without use; by the morning the device will be fully charged and useful.

Meaning while you have stated in the comments you went ahead and purchased a Microsoft Surface specific charger, you could easily use most any USB C phone charger or walk over to any nearby store that would sell such things and purchase a charger that will work fine with this device.

Answer (score 1):

> It has a USB-C socket on it but i'm not sure if that's for charging(inputting power), or if it's for plugging in a USB-C device, or for either?!

Most older Microsoft Surface devices don’t support being charged through a Type-C connection. There are exceptions to that statement, this article [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/usb-c-and-fast-charging-for-surface-d320ab19-e4ed-c36d-7458-7d7aec69d34a), has a list of those devices.

Your device is a Microsoft Surface Go 2 and this does indeed mean your device supports being charged over an applicable Type-C Power Delivery connection.

> [image]

If the device is not charging and you are certain that the connection is providing enough power then the battery is likely the problem and should be replaced.

[USB-C and Fast Charging for Surface](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/usb-c-and-fast-charging-for-surface-d320ab19-e4ed-c36d-7458-7d7aec69d34a)

[How to charge Surface](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/how-to-charge-surface-d03cc785-30d5-2263-5eda-1733abd6e3ac)

Comment: I actually doubt you have a Surface Pro 3 since it doesn’t actually have a Type-C port on it.

Comment: i've included a bunch more pictures.. one of the sides has a hole that looks like a slot, and a round hole, and what looks rather like a usb-c connector(is that a usb-c?) and if it's not a usb-c, then any idea what laptop it is? it has microsoft's logo on it as you see from one of the pics

Comment: this surface go 3 looks similar to mine  https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/d/surface-go-3/904H27D0CBWN/L395?activetab=pivot:overviewtab   and specific pic  from gallery on that page https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE4P0rI?ver=0240&q=90&m=6&h=705&w=1253&b=%23FFFFFFFF&f=jpg&o=f&p=140&aim=true

Comment: You said the device was a Surface Pro 3 which released back in 2012 with Windows 8.1 while the device you say it looks like is a device that comes with Windows 11. The provided screenshots are to low quality to reference in my answer

Comment: I didn't say the device was a surface pro 3, I said it has no label, and I said " I have a vague recollection of msinfo32 saying that it was MS Surface Pro. (maybe surface pro 3, I don't recall)."   The name Go in there rings a bell. So I think maybe it's an Ms Surface Go 3.  Like that link. Not sure which windows it has whether it's 8 or 10 or 11

Answer (score 0):

I am glad that I am not the only one in this frustrating situation. I wonder if your Surface Pro 2 is now charging? I did as you, attempted to charge it through the Usb slot w 15.4 vdc, and I am praying I haven't damaged anything while waiting for a "Power Delivery" friendly charger from China. Thanks to everyone for their assistance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).